# React JS : Check Email Id is valid or not along with comma separated email id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have input field which have prefilled email Id. I can change its value to one valid email id or multiple emailIds using **comma separated**. I am facing one issue is that it is not validating that the email id is valid or not. no matter it is one email id or multiple email id using **comma separated**

Below is the code that I have tried.

```js
import React, {Component } from 'react'

class Email extends React.Component{

 sendContactEmailId
 getCommaSeparateValue

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      emailValue : "abc@gmail.com",
      error:''
    }
  }

  checkEmailInput = (value) => {
    const regEx = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

    var result = value.replace(/\s/g, "").split(/,|;/);        

    for(var i = 0;i < result.length;i++) {
        
        if(!regEx.test(result[i])) {
            this.setState({
                error : 1,  
            })
        }

        this.setState({
            error : 0,
            emailValue : value,
        })
    } 

if(this.state.emailValue.indexOf(',') > -1){

        let getEmailId = this.state.emailValue.substr(0, this.state.emailValue.indexOf(','));

        this.sendContactEmailId = getEmailId,
        this.getCommaSeparateValue = this.state.emailValue.substr(this.state.emailValue.indexOf(",") + 1)
    
        console.log("Send Contact Email : " , this.sendContactEmailId)
        console.log("Get Comma Separate Value : " , this.getCommaSeparateValue);

        this.arrayOfString = this.getCommaSeparateValue.split(',');
        console.log("Array of String: " , this.arrayOfString);

    }      
}

changeValue = (value) => {
  this.setState({
    emailValue: value
});
}
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.emailValue} 
          onBlur={(e) => this.checkEmailInput(e.target.value)}  onChange={e => this.changeValue(e.target.value)}
          
        />
        {
            this.state.error === 1 ?

            <span>Invalid Email</span> : ''
          }
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default Email
```

Any help would be great.

thank you.

Comment: use `input type="email"` instead of text and you get yourself a perfect validation. No need for javascript validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting error to 0 everytime in the validation `for` loop.

You need to check for `else` case when setting error value to 0.
*(Meaning, you need turn off the error only if `regEx.test` passes.)*

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  if (!regEx.test(result[i])) {
    this.setState({
      error: 1
    });
  } else {
    this.setState({
      error: 0,
      emailValue: value
    });
  }
}
```

And also, I'd recommend you to put the positive test case in the `if` as it makes the code more readable and causes less cognitive load.

```
  // Check for positive instead of negative.
  // It improves the readability and
  // put less cognitive load.
  if (regEx.test(result[i])) {
    this.setState({
      error: 0,
      emailValue: value
    });
  } else {
    this.setState({
      error: 1
    });
  }
}
```

**Working demo**
[image: Edit 0oo99yjj3l]

---

To answer the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51595856/react-js-check-email-id-is-valid-or-not-along-with-comma-separated-email-id?noredirect=1#comment90159278_51596504),

You can simply split the string and filter out empty records.
You need `filter` to get rid of empty strings (refer to the demo below).

*Run the code snippet to see it work.*

```js
let result = "xyz@gmail.com, ".split(",").map(email => email.trim()).filter(email => email);
console.log(result);

result = "xyz@gmail.com, ".split(",").map(email => email.trim());
console.log(`result without filter`, result);

result = "xyz@gmail.com, y@y.com".split(",").map(email => email.trim()).filter(email => email);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: it worked. thank you so much. just one thing. How can I extract first comma separated email ids in array which doesn't contain space or any special characters. by that I mean I have `abc@gmail.com , xyz@gmail.com, pqr@gmail.com` . I want only those email ids which occurs after first comma and store them in an array. I have edited my question here.

Comment: Thank you. one issue is that, it allows me to have a space in between email id. for example , if I have `abc @xyz.com , d ef@gmail.com` then it consider as a valid email id and it store the comma separated values like `[d, ef@gmail.com]` . How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: @BrijeshPatel I believe it'd be better to ask another question as it could be hairy to take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

If input param is "a@gmail.com,b@gmail.com,c@123";

In order to validate email, first split with ',' and then validate the list of emails using isEmailsValid function.

```
const input = "a@gmail.com,b@gmail.com,c@123";

const emailList = input.split(',');

const emailValidationResult = isEmailsValid(emailList);

/* 
* if result is true then the list of emails are valid
* else list of emails are not valid
*/


// Function to validate list of emails by iterating through the list.
isEmailsValid = (emailList) => {
    for(let i=0; i<emailList.length; i+=1){
        const regEx = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
        if(!regEx.test(email)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```